# Aggregating Different Column Types With Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

I have a schema that looks something like this:

```
id     type      date
1      like      2013-12-25
2      comment   2013-12-25
3      like      2013-12-26
4      comment   2013-12-26
```

What I am trying to do is aggregate and count all the likes and comments on a specific and retrieve them in a single query. Right now I am using this:

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN type = 'like' THEN COUNT(id) END)  as likes, 
(CASE WHEN type = 'comment' THEN COUNT(id) END)  as comments,
date_trunc('day', date)
FROM
my_table
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', date), type
```

The problem is, the rows are not returning in a way that aggregates that data correctly. So how can I retrieve different values on the same column with a group by?

Also, the database being used is Postgres but a Mysql solution with be acceptable answer as well.

Comment: Try something like:

    SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'like' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as likes, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'comment' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as comments,
    date_trunc('day', date)
    FROM
    my_table
    GROUP BY date_trunc('day', date)

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level, e.g with a simple loop in PHP

Comment: I could mark that right if it was an answer

Comment: don't mind if you add it yourself as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
    SELECT  SUM(IF(type ='like',1,0) )as Likes, 
            SUM(IF(type='comment',1,0)) comments, 
            DAY(DATE) 'day'
    FROM `test_types`
    GROUP BY  DAY(DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DAY(tt.DATE) 'day', SUM(tt.type ='like')AS Likes, 
       SUM(tt.type='comment') comments
FROM `test_types` tt
GROUP BY DAY(tt.DATE)
```